# Paypal API version : can using an older version prevent payments to go through?

Tags: paypal

Payment via PayPal credit/debit cards apparently ceased to function entirely on my website since a month ago.

I see the version specified in the code is 94.0 whereas the current version is  ([99.0](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/release-notes/)). Can this be the reason why payments don't work anymore?

Comment: Although they will retire older versions, they are usually available for some time upon a new release. Do you get any specific error messages when attempting to take a payment?

Comment: Actually nothing happens. I do $response = $paypal -> request('DoDirectPayment', $requestParams + $creditCardDetails + $payerDetails + $orderParams); then I test if( is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Success'), doing A if so and B if not. But neither A nor B are executed. Execution just stops...